# SVG or Canvas bevel & emboss to find center-line of text

Tags: svg, canvas

The photoshop bevel & emboss effect makes it easy to find the central 'ridge' which   coincides with the center-line of text characters. This is done by increasing the appropriate effect settings to max-out the bevel, thereby creating such a ridge.

[image: Photoshop example]

*This Photoshop example was processed to further accentuate the center ridge*

Is it possible to achieve the same effect with an SVG filter or Canvas technique in the browser?

Once this effect is in place, I could obtain the coordinates of the center line which I want.

Alternatively, is there an existing algorithm to get this center line via mathematical means from a raster image or vector shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow this one tickled my fancy, although I am not sure this is an efficient way to get a result.

What is the center line? I define it as the set of all points inside the contour that fullfill the following condition: There must be at least one straight line going through the point where the distance to the nearest contour line is a local maximum along the line just at that point. In practice, testing a horizontal and a vertical line is enough.

I tried to implement that using two functions from the [SVGGeometryElement](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/types.html#InterfaceSVGGeometryElement) interface: `.getPointAtLength()` and `.isPointInFill()`. The second one has so far only been implemented in Chrome, so that is the only browser this will work with.

The `<text>` element does not implement the `SVGGeometryElement` interface, so it must be converted to a `<path>`. That is something that cannot be done in a browser, you'll need an appropriate grafics program for that.

Finding, for 1000 * 500 points, which of ca. 5000 points along the contour of the two letters is the nearest one is a lot of computation. Therefore this contains a crude mechanism to only test those contour points that are in the vincinity. Nonetheless, give it a few seconds to complete. If you compute only one letter at that size and halve the canvas size, the execution time will aproximately quarter.

```js
const width = 1000;
const height = 500;

const letter = document.querySelector('path');
const svg = document.querySelector('svg');
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = 'white';

function isInside(x, y) {
    const point = svg.createSVGPoint();
    point.x = x;
    point.y = y;
    return letter.isPointInFill(point);
}

// a 21 * 11 array of arrays
const fields = new Array(21).fill(0).map(() => {
    return new Array(11).fill(0).map(() => []);
});

// a list of points along the contour
const length = Math.floor(letter.getTotalLength());
Array.from(new Array(length), (x, i) => {
    return letter.getPointAtLength(i);
}).forEach(point => {
    // find out if a contour point is inside a 100 * 100 rectangle
    let rx1= Math.round(point.x / 100) * 2;
    let ry1 = Math.round(point.y / 100) * 2;
    // or a 100 * 100 rectangle that is offset by 50
    let rx2 = Math.round((point.x + 50) / 100) * 2 - 1;
    let ry2 = Math.round((point.y + 50) / 100) * 2 - 1;
    // push the point into all four lists for the rectangles it is part of
    fields[rx1][ry1].push(point);
    fields[rx1][ry2].push(point);
    fields[rx2][ry1].push(point);
    fields[rx2][ry2].push(point);
});

const data = new Float32Array(width * height);

for (let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        // only handle points inside the contour
        if (isInside(x, y)) {
            // find out which 50 * 50 rectangle the inside point is part of
            const rx = Math.round(x / 50);
            const ry = Math.round(y / 50);
            // find the nearest contour point from the list for the
            // appropriate 100 * 100 rectangle
            const d = fields[rx][ry].reduce((min, point) => {
                const dist = Math.hypot(point.x - x, point.y - y)
                return Math.min(min, dist);
            }, 100);
            // store that distance value
            data[y * width + x] = d;
        }
    }
}

data.forEach((v, i, a) => {
    // find out if the distance to the nearest contour point
    // is a local maximum, vertically or horizontally
    const vert = a[i - width] < v && a[i + width] < v;
    const hor = a[i - 1] < v && a[i + 1] < v;
    if (vert || hor) {
        // color that point as part of the center line
        ctx.fillRect(i % width, Math.floor(i / width), 1, 1);
    }
});
```

```html
<svg width="1000" height="500" style="position:absolute">
    <path id="letter" d="M 374.512,316.992 H 220.703 L 193.75,379.687 Q 183.789,402.832 183.789,414.258 183.789,423.34 192.285,430.371 201.074,437.109 229.785,439.16 V 450 H 104.688 V 439.16 Q 129.59,434.766 136.914,427.734 151.855,413.672 170.02,370.605 L 309.766,43.6523 H 320.02 L 458.301,374.121 Q 475,413.965 488.477,425.977 502.246,437.695 526.562,439.16 V 450 H 369.824 V 439.16 Q 393.555,437.988 401.758,431.25 410.254,424.512 410.254,414.844 410.254,401.953 398.535,374.121 Z M 366.309,295.312 298.926,134.766 229.785,295.312 Z M 810.742,247.266 Q 852.051,256.055 872.559,275.391 900.977,302.344 900.977,341.309 900.977,370.898 882.227,398.145 863.477,425.098 830.664,437.695 798.145,450 731.055,450 H 543.555 V 439.16 H 558.496 Q 583.398,439.16 594.238,423.34 600.977,413.086 600.977,379.687 V 123.047 Q 600.977,86.1328 592.48,76.4648 581.055,63.5742 558.496,63.5742 H 543.555 V 52.7344 H 715.234 Q 763.281,52.7344 792.285,59.7656 836.23,70.3125 859.375,97.2656 882.52,123.926 882.52,158.789 882.52,188.672 864.355,212.402 846.191,235.84 810.742,247.266 Z M 657.227,231.445 Q 668.066,233.496 681.836,234.668 695.898,235.547 712.598,235.547 755.371,235.547 776.758,226.465 798.437,217.09 809.863,198.047 821.289,179.004 821.289,156.445 821.289,121.582 792.871,96.9727 764.453,72.3633 709.961,72.3633 680.664,72.3633 657.227,78.8086 Z M 657.227,421.289 Q 691.211,429.199 724.316,429.199 777.344,429.199 805.176,405.469 833.008,381.445 833.008,346.289 833.008,323.145 820.41,301.758 807.812,280.371 779.395,268.066 750.977,255.762 709.082,255.762 690.918,255.762 678.027,256.348 665.137,256.934 657.227,258.398 Z"/>
</svg>
<canvas width="1000" height="500" style="position:absolute"></canvas>
```

Comment: Can't wait to try this. I'm up a real creek lately, the idea is to use Adobe Illustrator's CEP extension to input a vector shape from a document and obtain this line so as to do more things in said document. The reason I'm looking to leverage the browser is because unfortunately Illustrator doesn't have the same ability to easily determine the center line as Photoshop does, and my mathematics aren't very strong. Thanks for giving me hope, and for your time!

Comment: As an addition: luckily Adobe's CEP does use Chrome in it so I'm encouraged.

Comment: Wow just ran snippet test, this works super! I really think I can make this work!

Comment: Is there any way to have no smaller segments which are perpendicular to the main spine which touch the contour edges? This happens to round shapes such as the letter "O", it creates a cross-hair pattern.

Answer (score 2):

SVG filters are a powerful feature that can be like photoshop in the browser.  You can achieve the desired result by chaining a handful of filter primitives together.

```
<filter id="filterData">
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5" />
    <feDiffuseLighting surfaceScale="500">
         <feDistantLight azimuth="90" elevation="90" />
    </feDiffuseLighting>
    <feComposite result="composite" operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" /> 
</filter>
```

The first primitive blurs the text.  Then a lighting primitive uses the result of the blurred primitive as a bump map to give the text depth.  You will have to play with the surfaceScale attribute depending to the thickness of the text.  The composite primitive will cut the final result to the area of the unfiltered text, the 'SourceGraphic'.

[codepen example]  https://codepen.io/lahaymd/pen/EdNXam

Comment: Thanks for the filter approach, it pertinent to the question and useful for my SVG filter knowledge.